# Redirect site url http to https in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, http, url, redirect, https

I want to redirect my existing site to HTTPS. Currently in browser if **URL** start with **HTTP** then it will show bad gateways error but i want to redirect site to **HTTPS**.

Comment: What have you put for your `$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.example.com/';`

Comment: i put this
$config['base_url'] = "http://dev.njoyful.com/";

Comment: `$config['base_url'] = "https://dev.njoyful.com/";` I think dev is subdomain?

Comment: okk i chaged it to $config['base_url'] = "https://www.njoyful.com/"; and $config['base_url'] = "http://www.njoyful.com/"; but in both case it still not working...

Comment: then I think will be a htaccess issue.

Comment: how can i fix it..?? any suggestion...??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101460/discussion-between-kalpak-savaliya-and-wolfgang1983).

Comment: @wolfgang1983 thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code and put these lines into **.htaccess** file (if not exists then create) at the root of project folder :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

And make sure that you have also using https protocol in your $config['base_url'] in config.php file like

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://yourproject.local/';
```

Comment: Make new `.htaccess` file and upload it.

Comment: how can i redirect all url except 1 url

Comment: @kalpaksavaliya, To exclude a uri, try something like this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^something/except_url$`

Comment: Will this redirect urls including images and apis?

Answer (score 3):

Add this in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

`Base_url()` should be

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.example.com/';
```

Comment: how can i redirect all url except 1 url